# How to choose the right cascade types for entity relationshships following best practices: JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, orm, hibernate-cascade

I have been working on Spring Boot and JPA for quite some time and this question is raised several times. How should one decide to choose the right cascade types for entity relationships?
A scenario-
I have 2 entities-
**User** and **Category**. Now, I want a many-to-many relationship between these entities such that the relationship follows following rules-

1. When any entity is deleted, the other side is not deleted.
2. The categories are pre-defined in the database, therefore, adding/updating the **user** entity must not add/update the **category** entity.
3. Any updation to **category** must not be propagated to **user** entity.

Can somebody please help me understand that how to decide the right cascade types. In the above scenario, its clear that I don't have to use **CascadeType.REMOVE**. But, I am not sure about others- **REFRESH, PERSIST** and especially **MERGE** and **DETACH**.
Please help!!

Comment: I'd highly recommend to obey everything Vlad Mihalcea and Thorben Janssen suggest. https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/ You will find tons of great advices on their blogs.